# How to give a result to a html page in python

Tags: python, html, django

I have a Django project setup and an HTML page in this project that is asking for a password, and a Python code that is checking that password to validate it, the two are connected, and the password is sent with the GET method and my question is how to respond to the password, after it was checked with valid or invalid depending on the case and how to integrate that response in my page

Comment: You would need to show your code so far.